# Transitioning to PvP in EVE

Tags: eve-online

Incarna has dragged me back into EVE from a long hiatus.  When I played before, I was a total carebear miner.  I want to start fresh and get into the world of PvP, but I'm unsure of where to start.

I've tried some of the combat mission lines, but they're geared towards completely new players.  I just park my cruiser and wait for my drones to take out the enemies while I get a snack.  Needless to say, this is extremely boring.  It's just as bad as the high-sec mining I used to do!

I feel as if I'm "supposed" to join a corporation to get trained somehow, but I would really rather be a solo pilot.  I don't think most corporations will take very kindly to me joining just to get some free tips and tricks, and then promptly leaving.

Charging into low-sec with a cheap ship feels like a suicide run, and **I don't think I'll actually learn anything from it.**

In short, **what's the best way for a long-time EVE player to get into PvP?**

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter nor am I an EVE player, but it seems to me that it's a bit unclear what you are asking here. What prevents you from just trying PvP? What have you tried so far? What have you thought about so far? etc.

Comment: You are pretty much asking for recommendations, advice and suggestions, thus it is impossible to provide you with a single 100% correct answer. Plus, just as Oak said, your post is not a true question; in fact, there aren't any question marks in it. Try to be more specific - in current form your 'question' is really much more suitable as a forum post, not a true Q&A site question.

Comment: @sarmackie I think the question is pretty clear.  "[...] but I'm unsure of where to start."  Regardless, I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Maxpm - it looks better now. Similarly to Oak, i am not an EVE player, and I hope I am wrong, but I fear this question, instead of giving you a true correct answer, might start a debate.

Comment: PvP corp is the easy answer, too bad they all ask for like 10m SP. Basically for the first half year of eve your supposed to station spin (which they nerfed) while knowing exactly what to train for PvP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to join a PvP corporation that teaches newbies, such as [Agony Unleashed](http://www.agony-unleashed.com/), then take courses from them. They offer [*excellent* training courses](http://www.agony-unleashed.com/wiki/index.php/Agony_Empire_Classes_and_Seminars) for non-members (for a fee), highly recommended.

Alternately, join [Eve University](http://www.eveuniversity.org/), and take PvP courses, both from E-Uni, and Agony. There's no skill requirement for E-Uni, it's for training total newcomers. (Minor note, they are frequently at war, when recruiting is closed, so it may take time to join - but it's worth it). The Uni is generally considered a transitional corporation, most people leave it after they feel they're proficient, for other corps.

Update: R.I.P, [Agony Unleashed](https://wiki.agony-unleashed.com/index.php/Main_Page). I can't find any articles on why, but they have disbanded.

Comment: Uni's PvP environment is extremely newbie friendly. Ship replacements, no requirements before being allowed to FC, etc.  I highly recommend it - and not just because I'm a unista, myself. :)